# How to destroy a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android app in which I use `LayoutInflator` to generate new layout. What the app does basically is -  Its has one imageview. When I click on a button, I change the layout to display multiple ImageViews (like 2x2 or 4x4). I am successful in displaying these layouts using the LayoutInflator. However, the previous Layout stays intact and the new Layout is displayed *over* the old Layout which, kind of, messes the whole layout. My question is - is there anyway to destroy the old layout before displaying the new one?

Edit:

Here is the code (on the onClick event that I'm using)

```
public void oneby1onClick(View view){
    RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, main,false);
    main.removeView(main);
    main.addView(view);
}

public void twoby2onClick(View view){
    RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.twoby2, main,false);
    main.removeView(main);
    main.addView(view);
}

public void fourby4onClick(View view){
    RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fourby4, main,false);
    main.removeView(main);
    main.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: Post the code of your application.

Comment: You don't destroy a layout, you replace it. And it seems you are doing that wrong because usually layouts don't appear on top of each other unless you really add it on top.

Comment: ^+1 I'm doing something like [this link suggests](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-layoutinflater-turorial.html) except that I am having the layout changed on the onClick events of buttons. @zapl - How do you replace a layout?

Comment: In Java you don't destroy objects manually, it's up to the Garbage Collector.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just make your layout invisible if that is the case.
This can be done quite easily programmaticaly:

```
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: `View.GONE != View.INVISIBLE` ;)

Comment: You should definitely not use `View.INVISIBLE`.

Comment: Just tried it, both `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE`. This makes the whole `View` disappear. Even the new `View` doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

According to @ookami.kb's suggestion I should use `main.removeAllViews();` instead of `main.removeView(main);`, that helped me.